# how to access react component props that pass as in function parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access component props that is pass in the function parameter.

```js
class Slider extends Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.children;
    }
}
export default ChildTypeMustBe(Slider, 'SliderItem');
```

```js
export default function ChildTypeMustBe(WrapperComponent, type) {

    // how can i access WrapperComponent props over here
    // Ex: WrapperComponent.props.children;
    
    return WrapperComponent
}
```

Comment: What is the use case for this? What are you trying to achieve? This pattern feels wrong somehow, can you elaborate why do you need this?

Comment: I want to check the child type of the Slider Component and throw some exception nothing else.

Comment: Like @TheWhiteFang says, the pattern feels wrong.

For one, I don't think you intended to default export `ChildTypeMustBe` from two different files. It would make more sense if you imported `ChildTypeMustBe` function into your `Slider` file and passed the component into it as a parameter.

For another, `ChildTypeMustBe` in the second file accepts `WrapperComponent` as a parameter and just returns it, so we have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Well if you want to check for the type of props you can use `prop-types`. It is the most used way to check it. You can read about it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the props of a React component,
because the props don't exist before the "class" was instantiated
(i.e. the React element was created).

E.g. when passing the React component `Slider` to `ChildTypeMustBe`,
the component is still something that is supposed to be "called"
(aka. instantiated) with some props, while the props, which will be passed to `<Slider ...>`
later, are unknown at this point.

You can only know details about a React *element*, i.e. the instantiated *component*.
E.g. you could access the React elements properties, if you'd write it like this:

```
ChildTypeMustBe(<Slider />, 'SliderItem')
```

But you don't want that.

What you (probably) actually want is to create a *new* component, that can "intercept"
any passed props, analyze them, and pass them through to the actual `Slider` component:

```
function ChildTypeMustBe(WrappedComponent, type) {
    return function( props ){
        console.log('type:', props.children.type, props.children.type === type);
        return <WrappedComponent { ...props } />;
    }
}
```

(Note that I renamed it to `WrappedComponent` instead of `WrapperComponent`.)